# What could be the root cause of my syntax error when parsing in my node file?

Tags: node.js, json, express, parsing, server

Recently, I have been working on a small full-stack application with React as my front end and Node as my back end. In my server, I am using an endpoint with a get request to pull my data from the database, which is in sqlite. It was working properly until I started re-migrating (rollback/latest) the columns into my database. I could retrieve my seed data from Insomnia using the get request. Eventually, I added new columns and it started throwing this error below.
'SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 8
at JSON.parse ()'
So I rebuilt the entire project, tried it on similar projects, and still no dice. My migrations and seed files ran perfectly fine. In my server file, I have some middleware with `server.use(express.json());`. I know this is one of the roots of my problem but I am not sure how to go about troubleshooting this. I have tried to reinstall packages and Node. Any suggestions/tips?
My server file code for reference:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');

// const testData = require('../testData'); 
const db = require('./dbConfig');

const server = express();

/*middleware*/
server.use(express.json());
server.use(cors()); 
server.use(helmet()); 

/*middleware*/
/*endpoints*/
server.get('/', (req,res) => (
    res.send('Good luck lol')
));

server.get('/orderforms', async (req,res) => {
    //GET all orderforms

    // res.json(testData);
    console.log("RECEIVED GET REQUEST");
    try {
    const orderforms = await db('orderforms');

    res.status(200).json(orderforms);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error.', error: err.message, stack: err.stack });
  }
});

server.post('/orderforms', (req,res) => {
    //Post an orderform
});

server.put('/orderforms/:id', (req,res) => {
    //Put an orderform
});

server.delete('/orderforms/:id', (req,res) => {
    //Delete an orderform
});

module.exports = server; //exports the server
```

I tried to remove the parser, which worked, but I need that to automatically parse the data. I had backtracked my steps and even rebuilt the entire project on the backend. When I tested the get request using a testData file it still threw the same exact error because of the express.json() middleware.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this error reported? Does it refer to any particular part of your code? If I had to guess, I'd say it's coming from the `express.json()` middleware trying to parse a request body that says its JSON but is invalid. If that's the case, the problem is client-side and has nothing to do with your server-side code

Comment: I received this error in my terminal before the get request even started. None of the log statements execute ( the RECEIVED REQUEST log). I have no client-side necessarily,  insomnia is just using a localhost route to pull the data I have populated in my database on that localhost server. Are you saying the issue could be with insomnia itself?

Comment: Do you mean the terminal where you run / start your server? The error should include a stack trace, please [edit] your question to include it

Comment: I would change the middleware order to helmet, cors then json. Please also include specific details about how you're making any requests